# How do you determine the power required for a phase shift keying modulation scheme?

Tags: digital-communications, phase, modulation

This [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying) has a diagram :

[image]

which shows how the message "11000110" is conveyed as a waveform.

I'm trying to understand how the power to transmit this message can be determined.

Do I need to integrate the magnitude of the I(t) and Q(t) signals to determine power? Is there a formula somewhere?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I'm assuming it depends on a bunch of cases.  Where can I find the power formula for each case?

Comment: Absent any precise mathematical formulation about the waveform details (just showing waveform shapes is _not_ enough), _all_ that can be said is that you need to integrate integrate the _sum_ of the _squared_ magnitudes of the I and Q waveforms to find the signal power. As to _what_ these integrals work out to be, there are general formulas for specific waveforms but whether any of those formulas are applicable to _your_ particular waveforms is something that that the readership of dsp.SE is quite unable to determine.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Assuming $I(t)$ and $Q(t)$ are known, are you suggesting the power formula would be: $$\int_0^{4T_s}I^2(t)dt + \int_0^{4T_s}Q^2(t)dt$$ ?

Comment: Well, the formula you wrote will give you the total _energy_ of the signal and to get the (average) _power_, you all need to _divide_ by $4T_s$

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Perfect. Thanks. If you want to post an answer to this question I can mark it correct.

Comment: You should write your own answer to your question, and maybe accept it after waiting a while.